# readfile not working with concatenation

Tags: php, readfile

**1.** I am using readfile to print the contents of a file:

```
<?php readfile ('osta/css/themes/selected.txt'); ?>
```

**2.** This works perfectly. But I now need to use ROOT_PATH. I add it like so:

```
<?php readfile (ROOT_PATH . 'osta/css/themes/selected.txt'); ?>
```

But nothing is printed.

**3.** To verify that I have the correct path I try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo (ROOT_PATH . 'osta/css/themes/selected.txt'); ?>">test</a>
```

which produces a working link to the file.

What am I doing wrong in step #2?

Comment: What is ROOT_PATH?  A href shouldn't have a filesystem path, it should have a URL.

Comment: `ROOT_PATH` is relative to your document root, but `readfile()` interprets pathnames relative to the computer's real root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ROOT_PATH` works in `href`, that means it's a pathname relative to the webserver's document root, not the root of the real filesystem. `readfile()` expects a pathname in the real filesystem, so you need to add the document root.

```
<?php readfile ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . ROOT_PATH . 'osta/css/themes/selected.txt'); ?>
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much I was losing my mind on this! Your solution works perfectly.